# A city bus travels the distance between two stops

Tags: algebra-precalculus, kinematics

A city bus travels the distance between two stops, moving on schedule, with an **average speed of 30 km/h**. One day he got into a jam, so the **average speed**, with which it travelled, was **5 km/h less than at usual**. By what average speed should the bus move to catch the delay?

> Answer: 37,5 km/h

I would be very grateful if you give me a hint. When I try it, I will share what I've got. With this problem, I can't even start.

Comment: Not enough information. How long is the bus moving at the lower speed and how long does it have to catch up?

Comment: @Klaus We have all the info we need. The bus moves back and forth between two stops, and according to the schedule it should keep an average speed of $30$. One time it kept an average speed of 25 one way, so what speed does it need to hold on the return in order to catch up to the schedule?

Comment: @Arthur Well, you just made up the additional info. This was not in the OP when I last checked.

Comment: What's the distance of the destination?

Comment: @Klaus It's not making up. It's the experience of having read hundreds, if not thousands, of problem statements from people who do not have English as their native language, and finding the information which is there, but not obviously so. I'm not chainging anything in my previous comment, I'm just rephrasing.

Comment: @Arthur I get what you are saying and I would have interpreted it in the same way, but I don't think it is helpful to interpret questions in the way they were probably meant to be asked. The first step to solve a question is usually to formulate it in a way that actually makes sense. Hence I asked the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The bus travels a distance $d$. If it travels at $25$ *km/h*, the time it takes is $\dfrac d{25}$. It order to catch the delay, it will have to move at a speed $v$, and the time it will take will be $\dfrac dv$. So, the total time will be $\dfrac d{25}+\dfrac dv$. And you want it to take the same time that it would it to make two journeys at $30$ *km/h* , which is $2\times\dfrac d{30}$. So…

Comment: Shameful, isn't it?

Comment: It isn't from me. At the moment I am trying to understand what you have written. I appreciate your help!

Comment: +1,I  wonder about the downvotes!!

Comment: +1 from me. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterMelech It's only one downvote now. The other one was canceled.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos and 2 upvotes by now, it's good to see the excellent job You're doing at MSE is honoured

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I can't clearly understand why we sum up $\frac dv$ and $\frac {d}{25}$ and then equate it with $2× \frac {d}{30}$. Can you try to explain it to me? Sorry if the question is silly but I can't got it.

Comment: Because to catch the delay means that the whole time spent (from the first stop to second one and then back to the first one) means that the whole time spent is the same as in an ordinary day. And, in such a day, the time spent would be $\frac d{30}+\frac d{30}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, okay I got that but 25 is average speed, and I think this is the speed of all route (from the first stop to second one and then back to the first one).

Comment: The average speed for the return trip will be $\frac{75}2$ *km/h* and the average speed for the whole trip will be $\frac{100}3$ *km/h* then.

Answer (score 1):

Average speed is all about distance travelled and time taken. We don't know the exact distance here, but that's irrelevant as 1) all distances are the same, and 2) we don't care about the *actual* time taken. So you can just make a guess (60 kilometers, for instance, is often a choice that makes for rather easy calculation, or 30km, making for 60 km round trip). Or be general and say "The distance is $d$ kilometers". The answer you find in the end will be the same.

So, with such a guess in mind, how long does the trip take according to the schedule? How far behind schedule is the bus due to traffic? How much time does it have to travel back? How fast does that mean that it's going?

Comment: +1 from me. Thank you!